# How does the fstab file read the system?

Tags: boot, fstab

I understand that the file fstab serves to know how, where, and with what options to mount each of the partitions, including the root partition. But, how can it be that the system reads the file fstab, if it is assumed that the root partition is not mounted until the system reads the fstab file and knows how to mount the root partition? When is the root partition mounted?

Comment: That is what the initrd file is for.

Comment: Related question: [How does a kernel mount the root partition?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9944/how-does-a-kernel-mount-the-root-partition)

Comment: So, what is the use of specifying the options of the root partition in fstab if they are already in initrd?

Comment: @Daniel It allows for the root filesystem to be remounted with the mount options specified in that file.